# Trouble using font-awesome-rails with a HAML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, frontend, haml, font-awesome

I am currently trying to change from an existing svg file in the following section of a HAML file:

```
.pokecon-btn-search-lg
   %i.btn.w100= image_tag "icons/search_white.svg", class: "pokecon-img-icon-search"
   %input.pokecon-btn-search-lg-submit{type: "submit", value: ""}
```

The goal is to switch over to the font-awesome search icon which is usually called into HTML by

```
<i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

The gem font-awesome-rails is installed, and called into `application.css.scss` via `@import "font-awesome";`

In order to start get the line into the HAML file, I was advised to create an image helper like so:

```
module  ImagesHelper
  def fa(name)
    return "<i class='fa #{name}' aria-hidden='true'></i>"
  end
end
```

This allowed me to change the HAML file into:

```
%i.btn.w100
  = fa 'fa-search pokecon-img-icon-search'
  %input.pokecon-btn-search-lg-submit{type: "submit", value: ""}
```

Unfortunately, this is just rendering the text `<i class="fa fa-search pokecon-img-icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>` on top of the button instead of the actual icon that is needed. I have tried restarting the rails server and running bundle install again just in case, but the issue persists.

I am not super confident with HAML files so I would not be surprised if I am heading in completely the wrong direction with things here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without the helper first, then work out how to get the HAML into the helper method later.

This ought to work:

```
%i.btn.w100
  .fa.fa-search.pokecon-img-icon-search{ "aria-hidden" => true }
  %input.pokecon-btn-search-lg-submit{ type: "submit", value: "" }
```

Comment: I removed the helper file and switched out the code for your example. After restarting the rails server, I now get this message:

`Unparsable Ruby code is given to attributes:  aria-hidden: true `

Is it possible there is an issue elsewhere?

Comment: Oops. That's because there's a hyphen in the symbol name. My bad.

Comment: Fixed it. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

The string being returned by your helper isn't marked as [`html_safe`](https://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe) you can fix this by using:

```
return "<i class='fa #{name}' aria-hidden='true'></i>".html_safe
```

but, then if `name` can be modified by a user they can inject whatever they want into that string. (Try calling it with `<%= fa('\'"><script>alert("Hello");</script>') %>`) Instead I would do something like

```
content_tag :i, '', 'class' => ['fa', name], 'aria-hidden' => true
```